# Mercurial .hgignore file not working

Tags: mercurial, windows-8.1, hgignore

So I am new to Mercurial. I am trying to ignore all .class files and .orig files. I am using Windows 8.1

I created a .hgignore file and put the following inside:

```
#this is .hgignore 
syntax: glob
*.class 
*.orig
#end of file
```

When I type hg status I get

```
? .hgignore
```

Someone said I need to save in ANSI so I opened it in notepad and saved it in ANSI format and as All Types for my type option.

I am not sure if there is a syntax problem or something else. The file .hgignore is in the same folder as the .hg folder. So the path would look like:

```
\P1\.hgignore 
\P1\.hg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is not working? `hg status` only shows `.hgignore` so it seems to be working fine. Are you looking for a way to ignore the `.hgignore`  file itself?

Comment: no. I am probably being dumb. I was under the impression that it should show a list of the files that are being tracked. It isnt showing all of my .java files though, only the .hgignore

Comment: By default it only shows new and modified files. You can use the `-A` switch to show all files. Run `hg help status` for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `hg status` only shows new and modified files. You can use the `-A` switch to show all files.

Run `hg help status` for more details.